# Using facebook insights for facebook application and like-box code

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I have a single-page website with a like-box on it. The like-box is set up for facebook page (to which I have admin rights) and is working correctly. However the insights are not being logged in the application that the like box references.

To set up the like box I created a facebook application with the belief (maybe incorrectly) that in doing so I would see some insigts relating to the like-box from within the application. However I am getting no insights. I think I have missed something fairly obvious so let me show you my code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
    <!-- Facebook Metatags -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/test/logo.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Site"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/test/index.html"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Test Video"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="***myAppID***" /> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({
    appId  : ***myAppID***,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

//A couple of facebook events that I am tracking using google analytics go here - this works wonderfully by the way :-)

}; 


(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***myAppID***";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/myPage" width="300" data-height="60" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>

</body>

</html>
```

Within the settings for the facebook application:

- I have disabled Sand Box mode
- App Domains: mysite.com
- Select how your app integrates with Facebook: Website with Facebook
  Login, URL: http://www.mysite.com/test/index.html

I see that the facebook SDK is taking myAppID twice (surely not 100% correct) but I can't find any documentation to say what the correct usage is - so I have just included both!

So what have I not done or is it simply not possible to get facebook insights on a like-box that is on an external URL?

Answer (score 0):

Insights for a website, will only give you the website you define. So it will only collect data on like boxes associated with the website not the Facebook page

- http://www.mysite.com and
- http://www.facebook.com/myPage

will not be clumped under the same insights. To find insights for your page, go to your page insights.